# Concatenating strings in QTP

Tags: string, qtp, hp-uft

I'm trying to concatenate two strings in QTP using the "+" operator (I've also tried &)

```
string1 = "Plan number:" 
string2 = "5682"
newstring = string1 + string2
msgbox newstring
```

When I run the message box, the string appears as "Plan number: 5672". However, when I try to take this string and set a WebEdit on the internet equal to this value, it runs the error that the "parameter is incorrect" when in the past I had been setting it to a string. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you show how are you setting the value in WebEdit? When I tried on a test page - `Browser("IE").Page("Pages - Welcome").WebEdit("WebEdit").Set newstring` - it worked fine.

Comment: @PankajJaju Yes. I have Browser("RAM").Page("General").WebEdit("name").Set newstring

Comment: Is the webedit editable? Or does it only accept numeric values?

Comment: Run object spy on that webedit and check native properties. Check whether the input you are providing is acceptable or not. Incorrect parameter error is generally thrown when the input value provided is not acceptable to the object , in this case the webedit. By incorrect parameter i mean the colon symbol or the length of your string

Comment: I think the string was too long, and that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks!